# L2TP/IPsec through HTTP Port 80

Tags: vpn, http, ipsec, l2tp, tunnel

i got an VPN (L2TP/IPsec) Tunnel running on my synology nas. my router is configured for vpn passthrough. so everything is fine. furthermore i got an webservice running on port 80.

now i got the problem, that i spend most of my time in an environment where all ports are locked exclude the http ports (80/443).

my question: is it possible to tunnel l2tp/ipsec throught port 80? how can i achieve that? furthermore: is there a possibility to map e.g. www.myurl.com/vpn to my vpn server? so that my webservice is able to run parallel to the port 80 vpn redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong) `L2TP`/`IPSEC` doesn't work on port 80 (due to different protocol (!=TCP)), maybe you want to look into [OpenVPN - Open Source VPN](http://openvpn.net/) as a end solution for yourself.

Comment: so its not working per definition.. i thought about using l2tp/ipsec cause of security issues, but.. ok :)

Comment: openvpn solved my issue! furthermore there is an port-sharing option for e.g. port 443.. so i can provide http/https via port 80/443 during i am able to connect openvpn through port 443 :) great!